# Equivalent of window.scrollY for a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What is the best way to detect how much a user scrolled Vertically in a `div` element using plain JS?
These are snippets from my code:

html

```
<div id="blaaaa">
<!-- DIV CONTENT -->
</div>
```

js

```
document.getElementById('blaaaa').addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);

handleScroll(e) {
  // I want to use an equivalent of window.scrollY but for a single div element
  var scrolled = window.scrollY;
  // ...
},
```

How can I do that?

I appreciate your answers. Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop):

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("scroll", evt => 
  console.log(evt.target.scrollTop)
)
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: cyan;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the question is how best to detect how much a user has scrolled vertically in a div element using JS, which for me also means having easy-to-read code, then this is it (but that's my personal opinion).

```js
const scrollVal = document.getElementById('scroll-val')
  ,   blaaaaElm = document.getElementById('blaaaa')
  ;
blaaaaElm.onscroll=e=>
  {
  scrollVal.textContent = blaaaaElm.scrollTop;
  }
```

```css
#blaaaa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<p id="scroll-val">0</p>

<div id="blaaaa">
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
</div>
```